# Search and replace text in a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, replace, full-text-search, rowfilter

I am trying to search and replace a specific text in all the rows.I have managed to search the text in all the rows and display it accordingly but i don't know what to do with replacing.I have tries this but it doesn't seen to work.Here is the code.

```
  private void button7_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        string filterBy;
        filterBy = "Stringtext Like '%" + textBox6.Text + "%'";
        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterBy;
        int rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows-1; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString().Replace(textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);       
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Try dataGridView1[2, i].Value = dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString().Replace(textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the loop:

```
dataGridView1[2, i].Value = dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString().Replace(textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
```

Comment: I am really sorry, i was writting this down when you had allready posted yours. :) I only saw your post when i pressed on submit...

Comment: it ggives this error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."When i do it without the assignment it doesn't give that error :/

Comment: I think it should be dataGridView1[i, 2].Value = dataGridView1[i, 2].Value.ToString().Replace(textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);  The row is first and then the column...

Comment: Nah the first argument in dataGridView1[COLUMN, ROW]. I imagine your column index is wrong.

Comment: what is the value of DataGridView1.ColumnCount

Comment: Add a breakpoint and at the loop and see when you get this error.

Comment: datagridview1.columncount=9;

Comment: Yes the code did work .Actually the filtered rows which i searched  were 20 and the actual rows were 52..That's why it was giving the error.